# How to make a Raphael fill pattern move with the element? (background image position relative to the element)

Tags: svg, raphael, background-image

How can I give a Raphael element a fill that moves as the element moves, like how the CSS `background-image` of a `position: absolute;` HTML element would keep the same position relative to its location as it moved?

Here's an example demo: how can I make the background image pattern of the Raphael element (the triangular path) behave the same while dragged as the HTML element (the square div)?

### http://jsbin.com/oxuyeq/8/edit

---

This question is essentially the opposite of **[How to make a pattern “fixed” in Raphael.js / IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790911/how-to-make-a-pattern-fixed-in-raphael-js-ie)** with the polarised glasses simulator - I want to make the IE-specific behaviour they were trying to avoid happen consistently, in all browsers (including IE8).

As detailed in that other question, in IE8 (VML) only, the Raphael element behaves how I want; but even this is erratic: various things like calling `setSize` on the `paper` element or re-defining the fill (essentially, anything forcing a redraw) cause it to switch to the other behaviour.

---

There's a [question similar to this for pure SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407240/how-to-make-svg-image-pattern-fill-move-with-object), but without any good answers at time of writing, and certainly none that work for Raphael.

---

**Edit 2**: Watching what happens in SVG mode, it seems that every Raphael transform also automatically does the same matrix transform to the svg `<pattern>` element. I think this is what causing the behaviour I'm trying to avoid - I think `patternContentUnits` and `patternUnits` are unrelated. There's an unresolved issue that seems related here (highlighting the same problem with clip-rect, next to the line `this.pattern && updatePosition(this);`) - https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/638

So one possibility might be [to define a custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627105/raphael-js-custom-attributes/9418963#9418963) that applies a transform to the element without also applying it to the pattern. Sounds difficult - might require hacking Raphael or duplicating lots of Raphael transform code. Hopefully there's some other way. And [god help us making this work in VML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471380/how-to-debug-or-see-vml-ouput-in-ie-e-g-from-raphael)...

---

**Edit 3:** Some potentially relevant information, it's not just path fills that have this problem. Raphael `image` elements created with `paper.image()` don't have this problem in SVG mode but have a very similar problem that is really bad in IE8 VML mode. **[Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/ojutoy/8/edit)** of several ways to make image elements move, and here's a side-by-side comparison showing how they all work flawlessly in non-IE and all fail in IE:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I recently stumbled on a similar problem. I couldn't find a working solution anywhere, so I came up with my own. I used the answer by @user568458 as a starting point. First I changed the updatePosition function like so:

```
 updatePosition = function (o) {
    if(!o.data("relativeFill")) { //data is a custom store for user's properties
        var bbox = o.getBBox(1);
        $(o.pattern, {patternTransform: o.matrix.invert() + " translate(" + bbox.x + "," + bbox.y + ")"});
    }
},
```

I also changed the `fill` case of `setFillAndStroke` function like so:

```
var relativeFill = o.data("relativeFill"),
isURL = Str(value).match(R._ISURL);
if (isURL) {
    el = $("pattern");
    var ig = $("image");
    el.id = R.createUUID();
    $(el, {x: 0, y: 0, patternUnits: relativeFill ? "objectBoundingBox" : "userSpaceOnUse", height: 1, width: 1});
    $(ig, {x: 0, y: 0, "xlink:href": isURL[1]});
    el.appendChild(ig);

    (function (el) {
        R._preload(isURL[1], function () {
            var w = this.offsetWidth,
                h = this.offsetHeight,
                bbox = o.getBBox();
            $(el, {width: 1, height: 1});
            $(ig, {width: relativeFill ? bbox.width : w, height: relativeFill ? bbox.height : h});
            o.paper.safari();
        });
    })(el);
    o.paper.defs.appendChild(el);
    $(node, {fill: "url(#" + el.id + ")"});
    o.pattern = el;
    o.pattern && updatePosition(o);
    break;
}
```

Then whenever you want to use it you have to set `yourElement.data({ relativeFill: true })`

Here's a working example with relative and repeated fill: https://codepen.io/mmazur/pen/Gmebrj?editors=0010

---

I agree with @user568458, this solution is very ugly and might stop working with a future Raphael update. However, Raphael hasn't been changing much lately so I'm fine with taking this risk.

---

EDIT: Fixed a bug described here: [Image blurry when using url fill pattern for svg circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33895786/image-blurry-when-using-url-fill-pattern-for-svg-circle)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

There's a rough workaround for this that doesn't require hacking Raphael core code, but does depend on a not completely stable IE bug, described  https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/177

It works by hiding the SVG pattern object from Raphael by renaming it in the Raphael object, causing `updatePosition()` to not be called. This stops Raphael moving the background image in SVG mode. In VML mode, IE8 has a bug whereby, even though the code moves the `<fill>` element, this isn't updated on the screen until a redraw is forced.

```
path.patternTmp = path.pattern;
delete path.pattern;
```

This has the same other downside as the suggestion below that in VML mode it relies on an IE bug. But it works for simple cases. I haven't tested fully enough to see if there are other side effects of this fix, but there shouldn't be - looked at Raphael's source code, it looks like `updatePosition()` is the only Raphael function that uses `element.pattern`.

### http://jsbin.com/oxuyeq/10/edit

Note that `path.pattern` has to be renamed like this every time an image fill is applied - so if you reapply the fill for any reason, you need to re-do this fix - and that re-applying the fill will 'fix' the IE bug we depend on causing the image to slip out of sync with the object.

---

**Original answer:** Here's a sort-of fix. It's ugly in two ways:

- For SVG, it relies on hacking Raphael core code (but only a small hack)
- For VML, it relies on an Internet Explorer redraw bug, and will fail if your code causes a redraw

But you can get relative positions, so long as your code doesn't trigger an IE redraw (e.g. by re-setting the element's fill).

Ideally, there would be a way of doing this that works robustly in IE VML rather than relying on a bug.

---

You can do this ugly almost-fix by **turning off the Raphael function `updatePosition()` somehow**. The behaviour described above isn't an SVG default, it's a Raphael feature defined in the `updatePosition()` function which appears to be designed to make Raphael SVG elements' behaviour match how VML elements *would* behave if Internet Explorer wasn't a bundle of bugs held together with bugs. Note that the `updatePosition()` function is *only* called in SVG mode - VML fills are *supposed* to behave this way by default (but don't reliably because of the redraw bug described in the above linked question...).

My (ugly) way of doing this is to modify the `updatePosition()` function code to this:

```
updatePosition = function (o) {
    if(!o.relativeFill) {  // <<< added this condition
        var bbox = o.getBBox(1);
        $(o.pattern, {patternTransform: o.matrix.invert() + " translate(" + bbox.x + "," + bbox.y + ")"});          
    }
},
```

...then, for each element you want to have a relative fill, you set `someElement.relativeFill = true;`

---

Note that **this isn't good practice** - e.g. a future Raphael update might use the relativeFill namespace for something else. It's just an example of a sticky plaster fix that (just about) works.

---

**re. VML mode:** In theory, you might be able to make this fix robust and not bug dependent by adding a similar condition to the place in the VML-mode Raphael functions `setFillAndStroke` and/or `setCoords` that set `fill.position` to a dynamic calculation. These seem to be the VML equivalent of `updatePosition()`. In theory, VML should by default set the fill relative to the shape so long as [`alignshape = true` for the fill element, which in theory should be true by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb229597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But, it doesn't seem to work like that in practice. From my testing, relying on the IE bug as above actually seems to be *more* robust than trying to get IE VML to work as documented. In my testing, it's quite difficult to get IE8 to redraw the fill: only resetting the fill seems to do it.