# Drawing within the clipping area of a path, or otherwise within a path-defined shape

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I need to draw a series of small circles at random within the area of a path. Let's say the path is a triangle. Is there a way to do this using Raphaël? I understand something like this may be computationally expensive, so that's another factor that's important here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like unfortunately you can't define a clipping path using Raphaël, according to this other post: [clip-path in Raphaël.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014673/clip-path-in-raphael-js)

However SVG does support it through the clipPath element. A demo is at http://sawyerhollenshead.com/writing/23/using-svg-clippath/

Comment: Raphaël only supports rectangular clipping (probably due to VML constraints), see the 'clip-rect' attribute, http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr.